# Can I extract the HTML contents of DIV that is in a data-module-group

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrap table(s) that are within a data-* div from the following page:

[https://www.fiba.basketball/eurobasket/2022/qualifiers/game/2202/Turkey-Croatia#|tab=boxscore](https://www.fiba.basketball/eurobasket/2022/qualifiers/game/2202/Turkey-Croatia#%7Ctab=boxscore)

All the different ways that I have tried using BeautifulSoup returns a blank because I assume the HTML contents is with the data-module which I am not sure I can access.

The inspected elements of the page is

```
<div data-module-group="game-boxscore" id="gamepage_boxscore">
<div data-module-name="GAME_BOX_SCORE" data-module-type="live" id="jet-game-boxscore"
</div><div class="tab_ajax_content" data-module-type="esi"><!-- GamePageBoxScoreModuleModel d45eda71-7aac-4017-b055-e70f29b1d352 19.05.2022 16:08:58.198 on vmssprodI000009 
 @moduleident(/en/Module/d45eda71-7aac-4017-b055-e70f29b1d352/adad72a7-4113-4201-ae49-5b994ca0158b)@ -->
```

The table itself is then within this DIV. Any help in regards to pointing me in the right direction, or even confirming if this is possible, would be appreciated.

Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are generated by an ajax call. So you need to get the data from that source. You can find the ajax url in the link you provided.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


url = 'https://www.fiba.basketball/eurobasket/2022/qualifiers/game/2202/Turkey-Croatia'
response  =requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
boxscore = soup.find('li', {'data-tab-content':'boxscore'})['data-ajax-url']

ajaxUrl = f'https://www.fiba.basketball{boxscore}'
response  =requests.get(ajaxUrl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
teamNames = [x.text.strip() for x in soup.find_all('header', {'class':'team_caption'})]

dfs = pd.read_html(ajaxUrl)

boxscore_df = pd.DataFrame()
for idx, df in enumerate(dfs):
    df['Team'] = teamNames[idx]
    boxscore_df = pd.concat([boxscore_df, df], axis=0).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output:**

```
print(boxscore_df.to_string())
               #            Players                             Min                             Pts                              FG                            2Pts                            3Pts                              FT                            OREB                            DREB                             REB                             AST                              PF                              TO                             STL                             BLK                             +/-                             EFF     Team
0              0       Shane Larkin                           27:10                              16                      5/8  62.5%                        1/2  50%                      4/6  66.7%                      2/3  66.7%                               0                               1                               1                               7                               2                               1                               2                               2                               9                              23   Turkey
1              2       Sehmus Hazer                           16:16                               9                        3/5  60%                        2/4  50%                       1/1  100%                       2/2  100%                               0                               1                               1                               1                               1                               1                               1                               0                              -2                               9   Turkey
2              9        Samet Geyik                           12:17                               0                         0/1  0%                          0/0  -                         0/1  0%                          0/0  -                               0                               4                               4                               0                               2                               0                               1                               1                              -3                               5   Turkey
3             10   Melih Mahmutoglu                           23:35                              12                       6/12  50%                      6/7  85.7%                         0/5  0%                          0/0  -                               0                               0                               0                               2                               0                               0                               0                               0                               5                               8   Turkey
4             13      Berkan Durmaz                           05:31                               0                          0/0  -                          0/0  -                          0/0  -                          0/0  -                               1                               1                               2                               0                               1                               1                               1                               0                               2                               2   Turkey
5             14     Furkan Haltali                           05:06                               2                        1/2  50%                        1/2  50%                          0/0  -                          0/0  -                               0                               0                               0                               0                               2                               1                               0                               0                               1                               0   Turkey
6             17        Berk Ugurlu                           16:06                               3                        1/4  25%                         0/1  0%                      1/3  33.3%                          0/0  -                               0                               0                               0                               1                               1                               1                               1                               0                              -4                               1   Turkey
7             18  Dogus Özdemiroglu                           04:28                               2                        1/2  50%                        1/2  50%                          0/0  -                          0/0  -                               0                               0                               0                               0                               1                               0                               1                               0                               0                               2   Turkey
8             19    Bugrahan Tuncer                           23:54                              17                       7/10  70%                        4/5  80%                        3/5  60%                          0/0  -                               0                               5                               5                               7                               3                               4                               1                               1                              10                              24   Turkey
9             21       Sertac Sanli                           28:05                              17                       8/10  80%                       7/7  100%                      1/3  33.3%                          0/0  -                               3                               3                               6                               2                               2                               0                               0                               1                               0                              24   Turkey
10            23     Alperen Sengun                           25:07                               6                        1/2  50%                        1/2  50%                          0/0  -                      4/6  66.7%                               3                               2                               5                               1                               2                               2                               0                               2                               7                               9   Turkey
11            61    Goksenin Koksal                           12:25                               0                         0/1  0%                          0/0  -                         0/1  0%                          0/0  -                               0                               1                               1                               0                               1                               0                               0                               0                               5                               0   Turkey
12  Team/Coaches       Team/Coaches                             NaN                             NaN                             NaN                             NaN                             NaN                             NaN                               0                               1                               1                             NaN                               0                               0                             NaN                             NaN                             NaN                             NaN   Turkey
13        Totals             Totals                             200                              84                    33/57  57.9%                    23/32  71.9%                      10/25  40%                     8/11  72.7%                               7                              19                              26                              21                              18                              11                               8                               7                               6                             107   Turkey
14             2    Goran Filipovic                           14:47                              12                      4/6  66.7%                        3/5  60%                       1/1  100%                       3/3  100%                               0                               3                               3                               2                               1                               2                               0                               0                               1                              13  Croatia
15             7     Jakov Mustapic                           20:01                               5                      2/3  66.7%                       1/1  100%                        1/2  50%                          0/0  -                               0                               3                               3                               1                               3                               1                               0                               0                             -11                               7  Croatia
16             8       Roko Prkacin                           15:39                               4                        2/5  40%                      2/3  66.7%                         0/2  0%                          0/0  -                               0                               0                               0                               5                               3                               1                               0                               0                              -3                               5  Croatia
17            11    Tomislav Gabric                           20:24                              13                        4/5  80%                       1/1  100%                        3/4  75%                       2/2  100%                               2                               2                               4                               0                               1                               0                               0                               0                              -6                              16  Croatia
18            12  Pavle Marcinkovic                           18:22                               2                       1/1  100%                       1/1  100%                          0/0  -                          0/0  -                               0                               1                               1                               2                               1                               1                               3                               0                               3                               7  Croatia
19            13  Antonio Vrankovic                           15:47                              10                       5/5  100%                       5/5  100%                          0/0  -                          0/0  -                               0                               0                               0                               2                               2                               1                               0                               0                               1                              11  Croatia
20            15         Miro Bilan                           24:13                              12                       6/10  60%                      6/9  66.7%                         0/1  0%                          0/0  -                               1                               2                               3                               2                               3                               2                               0                               0                              -7                              11  Croatia
21            23     Mateo Dreznjak                           21:13                               6                        3/5  60%                        3/4  75%                         0/1  0%                          0/0  -                               2                               0                               2                               0                               2                               0                               0                               0                               2                               6  Croatia
22            30      Dominik Mavra                           25:13                               4                      1/9  11.1%                        1/4  25%                         0/5  0%                       2/2  100%                               0                               1                               1                               3                               2                               0                               0                               0                              -7                               0  Croatia
23            33       Zeljko Sakic                           24:21                              10                      3/8  37.5%                        2/4  50%                        1/4  25%                        3/4  75%                               2                               3                               5                               3                               2                               3                               0                               0                              -3                               9  Croatia
24            34        Marin Maric  Did not play  - Coach decision  Did not play  - Coach decision  Did not play  - Coach decision  Did not play  - Coach decision  Did not play  - Coach decision  Did not play  - Coach decision  Did not play  - Coach decision  Did not play  - Coach decision  Did not play  - Coach decision  Did not play  - Coach decision  Did not play  - Coach decision  Did not play  - Coach decision  Did not play  - Coach decision  Did not play  - Coach decision  Did not play  - Coach decision  Did not play  - Coach decision  Croatia
25            41    Antonio Jordano  Did not play  - Coach decision  Did not play  - Coach decision  Did not play  - Coach decision  Did not play  - Coach decision  Did not play  - Coach decision  Did not play  - Coach decision  Did not play  - Coach decision  Did not play  - Coach decision  Did not play  - Coach decision  Did not play  - Coach decision  Did not play  - Coach decision  Did not play  - Coach decision  Did not play  - Coach decision  Did not play  - Coach decision  Did not play  - Coach decision  Did not play  - Coach decision  Croatia
26  Team/Coaches       Team/Coaches                             NaN                             NaN                             NaN                             NaN                             NaN                             NaN                               1                               4                               5                             NaN                               0                               1                             NaN                             NaN                             NaN                             NaN  Croatia
27        Totals             Totals                             200                              78                    31/57  54.4%                    25/37  67.6%                       6/20  30%                    10/11  90.9%                               8                              19                              27                              20                              20                              12                               3                               0                              -6                              85  Croatia
```

Comment: Easy as that! Thank you so much, re-visited this about 6 times but honestly didn't think it could be done. Appreciate you going above and beyond in your answer.